# Subtract Two Variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script, which cuts some timestamps down into the form `SS.sss` and stores this in a variable:

```
s1=$(echo $t1 | cut -c7-)
s2=$(echo $t2 | cut -c7-)
```

I would like to subtract `$s2` from `$s1` (and store as `$s3`) but I cannot get `expr` to work - is there another option?

Comment: What do `s1` and `s2` look like?

Comment: Check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429943/script-calculator-division

Comment: `s1` and `s2` are in the form `SS.sss` from a timestamp, so for example 24.260.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do most bash calculations like this:

```
s3="$((s2 - s1))"
```

Those are limited to basic operations on integers, if I recall correctly, so things like

```
s3="$(echo "$s2 - $s1" | bc)"
```

might be better.

Comment: `$(( ... ))` is part of the POSIX standard, but does not support floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as my accepted answer because this answer worked on my system, while the other did not.

Answer (score 4):

`expr` only handles integer arithmetic. You can use `bc`:

```
s3=$(echo "$s1 - $s2" | bc)
```

Comment: For some reason, this version will not work on my system - but thanks for the help!

Comment: It should be `$(...)`, not `$((...))`.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the edit devnull. I had arithmetic expressions on the brain.